# blogger post list using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, blogger

i'd like to make a grid view to my blog post using jquery mobile. But on JQM demo, i only found this..

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
        <img/>
        <h2>Newest Blog Post Title</h2>
        <p>Newest Blog Post Content</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img/>
        <h2>Second Blog Post Title</h2>
        <p>Second Blog Post Content</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img/>
        <h2>Third Blog Post Title</h2>
        <p>Third Blog Post Content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

my question is, how can i retrieve my blog post in order to use for above template...? I say thank you for any answers...

Zamm.

Comment: Retrieve post with Ajax.

Comment: hi omar, would you show me how to do it?

Comment: Google "ajax jquery" you'll find enormous examples. The first step, you need to know how to pull data from server using Ajax, the rest is easy.